# Is there a way to 'reset' a function once is called?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that enable interaction with a list of images and it works perfect, but then I create more images and call the function again and now it works well with the new images, but the first list of images are interacting with both the old and the new list at the same time.

I would like to reset or erase the event listeners in the first function once I call the second one (I wouldn't like to remove every event listener if possible )

Ima do sth small here to illustrate my point

```
if ( number == 1){
   interaction()
} else if ( number == 2){
  // A way to erase previous func here
  interaction()
}


function interaction(){
  let heart = document.getElementsByClassName("card-interaction3");
  const heartactive = document.getElementsByClassName("card-interaction3-active");
  

  for (let i = 0; i < heart.length; i++) {

        heart[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
            heartactive[i].classList.toggle("display")
        });


}
```

Thank you so much

Comment: I need to see the erasePreviousinteraction() function

Comment: Where is `titlecrtgif` gotten from

Comment: You can call [EventTarget.removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).  I suggest creating a function that adds a listener and returns a function that removes the listener that was added.  Then you can push all those functions into an array and call them all later.

Comment: You can also use an Abortable Listener as [shown here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#add_a_abortable_listener).  addEventListener accepts an AbortSignal option called `signal` that, when its `abort()` method is called, will remove the listener from the target.